# Activity is still showing leaked window which is already handled

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am getting a window leak when I am starting a free walk activity. I have handled that scenario but still don't understand why I am still getting.

Here is my code:

```
 private void showPopUp() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.wwmove_screen_popup);

    TextView mNo = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.move_no);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    mNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    TextView mYes = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.moveyes);
    mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            killAll();
            storeSegmentcompletdInformation("skipped");
            storeOneDayInformation("skipped");
            Intent gotoSummary = new Intent(WwFreeWalkMoveActivity.this, WwFreeWalkSummaryActivity.class);
            gotoSummary.putExtra(ParamConstants.SUMMARY_GOOGLEFIT_KEY, String.valueOf(stepCountGoogleFit));
            startActivity(gotoSummary);
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
08-18 10:38:53.172 28118-28118/com.mobiefit.walk E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mobiefit.walk.freewalk.activity.WwFreeWalkMoveActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{21f913f9 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-960,516} that was originally added here
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:364)
                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:274)
                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                  at com.mobiefit.walk.freewalk.activity.WwFreeWalkMoveActivity.showPopUp(WwFreeWalkMoveActivity.java:953)
                                                                  at com.mobiefit.walk.freewalk.activity.WwFreeWalkMoveActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(WwFreeWalkMoveActivity.java:1806)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2936)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:404)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:185)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:192)
                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19888)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window leaked exceptions are usually caused by dialogs which are not dismissed properly.
you have to dismiss the dialog
In your code 
use this

```
dialog.dismiss();

mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            killAll();
            storeSegmentcompletdInformation("skipped");
            storeOneDayInformation("skipped");
            Intent gotoSummary = new Intent(WwFreeWalkMoveActivity.this, WwFreeWalkSummaryActivity.class);
            gotoSummary.putExtra(ParamConstants.SUMMARY_GOOGLEFIT_KEY, String.valueOf(stepCountGoogleFit));
            startActivity(gotoSummary);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding to next activity or task. dismiss your `dialog.dismiss();` dialog.

```
     public void onClick(View v) {
            killAll();
            storeSegmentcompletdInformation("skipped");
            storeOneDayInformation("skipped");
            Intent gotoSummary = new Intent(WwFreeWalkMoveActivity.this, WwFreeWalkSummaryActivity.class);
            gotoSummary.putExtra(ParamConstants.SUMMARY_GOOGLEFIT_KEY, String.valueOf(stepCountGoogleFit));
            dialog.dismiss(); // here you just have to add one line.
            startActivity(gotoSummary);
        }
```